# Question about a tensor product of modules

Tags: tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

Let $M=\mathbf{Z}/2$, $N=\mathbf{Z}/3$, the free-module $\mathbf{Z}^{M \times N}$ and his sub-module $H$ generated by elements of the following forms $(m_1+m_2,n)-(m_1,n)-(m_2,n), (m, n_1+n_2)-(m,n_1)-(m,n_2), (am,n)-a(m,n), (m,an)-a(m,n), m, m_1, m_2 \in M, n ,n_1, n_2 \in N, a \in \mathbf{Z}$.

And then consider the quotient-module $\mathbf{Z}^{M \times N}/H=\mathbf{Z}/2 \otimes_{\mathbf{Z}} \mathbf{Z}/3$.
Then a bilinear map $\tau$ from $N \times M$ to the quotient module vanishes on $(1,1) \in M \times N$ and I would like to know if we can find a generator of $H$ that verify the following equality
\begin{equation}
(1,1)=(3.1,1)=(1,3.1)+\text{a generator of} H.
\end{equation}
Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I know that $a \otimes b =ab(\overline{1} \otimes \widetilde{1})$ for every $a \otimes b \in \mathbf{Z}/2 \otimes \mathbf{Z}/3$ so $(1 \otimes 1)$ is a generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer a different notation, namely $[x]_2$ and $[x]_3$ for the residue classes modulo $2$ and $3$.

First some general fact: if $M=Rx$ and $N=Ry$ are cyclic modules over the commutative ring $R$, then also $M\otimes_RN$ is cyclic, generated by $x\otimes y$.

Indeed, for a generic element of $M\otimes N$ has the form
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n r_ix\otimes s_iy=\Bigl(\,\sum_{i=1}^n r_is_i\Bigr)(x\otimes y)
$$
because you can move scalars past the tensor product. With more details
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n r_ix\otimes s_iy=
\sum_{i=1}^n r_is_ix\otimes y=
\Bigl(\,\sum_{i=1}^n r_is_ix\Bigr)\otimes y=
\Bigl(\,\sum_{i=1}^n r_is_i\Bigr)(x\otimes y)
$$
In your case $W$ is cyclic, generated by $[1]_2\otimes[1]_3$. On the other hand
$$
3[1]_2=[1]_2
$$
so you have
$$
[1]_2\otimes[1]_3=3[1]_2\otimes[1]_3=[1]_2\otimes 3[1]_3=[1]_2\otimes [0]_3
$$
so the generator is zero and consequently $W$ is the zero module.

Comment: azif00, egreg: thank you for your responses. I edited my question. Hope it makes more sense. Sorry for the confusion.